# Log-likelihood function of probit model

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, probit

I need help with the maximization of log-likelihood function of probit model. I don't understand how the term $s_i$ in the second derivative ended there as a standalone term? The $\Phi(s_i)$ is normal CDF, the $\phi(s_i)$ is normal pdf, and $s_i=\beta'x$.

[image]